# Beginners advice on server side file storage

Tags: sql-server, xml, repository, storage

I'm new to stack overflow so hi. I'm also pretty new to the programming scene so I'll try be as technically adept as possible.

Basically I'm designing and application that stores files and schema's on the server side.

The simple architecture is that there will be 2 databases. One for file storage and the other to hold XML files that point to the files.

I'm very new to this and after looking around at some different options (fedora commons, php nuke, remository) I'm feeling a bit lost and just looking for some advice or good paths on the topic.

For general information. The files being stored in the repository/ database will be quite small but there will be a lot of them. The XML schema will point towards the location of these files.

EG files location is /images/stackOverflow/mine.jpg

And the XML would look like

```
<images>
    <location>/images/stackOverflow/mine.jpg</location>
 </images>
```

The architecture is pretty flexible and theres no content management system in place so any advice is appreciated.

I done a search on stack but most questions were on client side storage instead of server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing documents you could look into a Document-Oriented Database or Document Management System.

[Document-Oriented Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_oriented_database)

You can also look at other NoSQL databases that may make more sense than a typical RDBMS that are XML based.

[XML Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database)

Yet another option is utilizing an RDBMS for document storage which allows you to organize documents by record and perform industry standard SQL queries to search for and retreive documents.